# PHP: Send mail with link

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

Im using following php code:

```
$mailacc = "example@example.com";

$subject = "Hello";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Mail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Open Link</a></p>
</body>
</html>
";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Noreply <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";

$mail = mail($mailacc, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But it dosent send the mail, when I remove the link and put in some text it workes. Why can't I have a link in my message? PS: $mailacc is my real email account.

Thx!

Comment: Please what is the error you see?

Comment: I get no error.. It just dosent comes to my email..

Comment: Check your junk folder in the mail.

Comment: COuld it be that a mail like that is seen as spam and gets blocked.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't send the mail, it's an issue with the server itself.. it is unable to send mails.
(Or otherwise: check the spam-folder)

Comment: +1 for spam-folder. That would certainly explain why a mail containing a single hyperlink wouldn't get delivered.

Comment: Yes.. It's in the spamfolder.. How do I change the code to not enter the spamfolder?

Comment: You must not add an hyperlinked text. Rather include the link itself without hyperlinking.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your exact code on my server, and I received the message fine.

Are you sure that your spam filter isn't detecting the link and sending it to a 'junk mail' folder?

Comment: Ive found it in my spam folder. Do you have any idea how to make it not end up in the spamfolder? Im using default settings in my gmail

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, I thought that 'reputation' is to be built over time to make certain mail sources trusted.  For example if you sent emails frequently to several parties, and they certified that the message was "Not Junk", it would deem that your mail source is genuine - you should do this to make the messages go in to your inbox.  It's a strange one, because all junk mail services are customised to different ways of working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly. I sent a mail to my account. And, no, it wasn't in the spam folder.

Comment: Ive check my spam folder, and there it was. Just dont know hoe to change it to not end up in the smap folder.. Im using default settnings on my gmail.

Comment: Maybe it's from your mail server, it probably has a bad record. You can mark it as not spam, so it comes to your inbox next time.