# How to insert a hyperlink in PHP email message?

Tags: php, email

I tried to do my own research but the following links did not help me.

[PHP Email & Hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066364/php-email-hyperlinks)
[PHP: Send mail with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661183/php-send-mail-with-link)

```
$subject = "Thank you for registering to " . SITE_NAME;

                    $mail_content = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <head>
                                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                                </head>
                                <body>

                                <div>
                                        <p>' . $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->lastname_name . ', thank you for registering to ' . SITE_NAME . '.</p>
                                        <p>Please click the following link to proceed to the Questionnaire "<a href =\"www.example.com\">www.example.com</a>"</p>


                                </div>
                                </body>
                                </html>';
```

In the email message I want there to be the link URL, when user clicks it, he gets redirected to the URL page. At this moment when I checked it, I receive the email but the link is plain text with quote marks around it. Like this "www.example.com"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If that's all you're doing: not enough, you need to tell the e-mail recipient you're actually sending HTML, **and** you need to put a protocol in front of the url (like ` http://`  or `https://`).

Comment: Both the links you posted could be used to be closed as a duplicate. How are you then using it in conjunction with mail?

Comment: If those links did not provide me with a solution for my code, it cannot be duplicate.

Comment: As Wrikken stated, you need to add `http://` to `www.example.com` as in `<a href =\"http://www.example.com\">www.example.com</a>` - and try removing the quotes in `"<a href =\"www.example.com\">www.example.com</a>"</p>` as in `<a href ="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a></p>`

Comment: Fred-ii ,it is still not a link. Is there any proper php code that turns the desired text into a link?

Comment: I've tested what I posted for an answer below.

Comment: @Nathalie Have you tried what I posted in my answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the escapes for your double quotes in

```
"<a href =\"www.example.com\">www.example.com</a>"
          ^                ^
```

and add `http://` or `https://`

```
"<a href ="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>"
```

or

```
<a href ="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
```

if you don't want quotes around it.

---

Tested with: (and assuming your `SITE_NAME` [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) has already been defined, and other variables).

```
<?php

define("SITE_NAME", "Our Website!"); // I added that

$subject = "Thank you for registering to " . SITE_NAME;

$mail_content = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div>
        <p>' . $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->lastname_name . ', thank you for registering to ' . SITE_NAME . '.</p>
        <p>Please click the following link to proceed to the Questionnaire "<a href ="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>"</p>


</div>
</body>
</html>';

echo $mail_content;
```

Comment: @Nathalie Always glad to be of help. Remember to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while sending email in php , i used `stripslashes()` with the email **body** and it worked .you can also try and seeif that works for you

```
$mail_content = stripslashes($mail_content);
```